# Why does my Array Formula only return one value?

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

So I have this data.

`|Col M    | Col N | Col O | Col P | Col Q | Col R|
 |<formula>|   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E  |`

I'm trying to put a formula into Column M, using `{=$N$6:$R$6&", "}`, but it only returns `A,` instead of `A, B, C, D, E`. Why does this happen?

Comment: @deanosaur, its right in the question... `{=$N$6:$R$6&", "}`

Comment: This is not the way to concatenate .. either you should use `&` or you can use `concatenate` excel function.

Comment: Yes, that would work if he put in each separate value, one-by-one. However `CONCATENATE` won't take a multiple-cell range or array arrgument, which is what the user is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish isn't available with any native Excel formulas (concatenating an array). The array formula you're using is simply returning the first result, which is all it can do really. You would have to write a custom function to concatenate an array. Something like

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ARRCONCAT(ByVal rng As Range, Optional ByVal sep As String = ", ") As String

If rng Is Nothing Then
    ARRCONCAT = xlErrNull
    Exit Function
End If

Dim c       As Range
Dim result  As String

For Each c In rng
    If result = "" Then
        result = c.Value
    Else: result = result + sep + c.Value
    End If
Next c

ARRCONCAT = result

End Function
```

Put that code into a new module in your workbook, then call it like so:

```
=ARRCONCAT($N$1:$R$1)
```

or

```
=ARRCONCAT($N$1:$R$1, ";")
```

Comment: I'm pretty much using a UDF right now to create it, but I thought there'd be an actual way to do it, all this time later. lol

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not, UDF's are the only way to accomplish this.